# Python import problems with image2gif

Tags: python, pip

I know I have all packages installed (pip freeze)
I am on a Windows 10 machine and am running python3.4 and am having weird dependency problems

test.py:

```
from images2gif import writeGif
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
import os

file_names = ['output\donkey-1.png', 'output\donkey-2.png']

images = [Image.open(fn) for fn in file_names]

size = (600,350)
for im in images:
    im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

filename = "test.gif"
writeGif(filename, images, duration=0.5, subRectangles=False)
```

running test.py gives the following errors, could not find this error anywhere else on the web

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from images2gif import writeGif
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\images2gif\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from images2gif import readGif as readGif
ImportError: cannot import name 'readGif'
```

Comment: Can you give a listing of the images2gif directory (C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\images2gif)? It appears there is no module readGif in that directory.

Answer (score 12):

I just looked at the [actual repository source code](https://bitbucket.org/bench/images2gif.py): it uses Python 2 style relative imports. That is, images2gif does not support Python 3 out of the box.

One solution for now might be to download [the sourcefile from pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/images2gif), extract that (not sure if Windows likes tar.gz files), cd into the directory and run 2to3 on it:

```
2to3 -w .
```

and then install it manually:

```
python3.4 setup.py install
```

---

But probably easier, just seeing the results of `2to3`: manually change the two import statements in your already installed package (in `__init__.py`):

```
-from images2gif import readGif as readGif
-from images2gif import writeGif as writeGif
+from .images2gif import readGif as readGif
+from .images2gif import writeGif as writeGif
```

because it appears everything else is PY3K compatible; the dots in front of `images2gif` in those two import statements make it proper PY3K relative imports.

Comment: Wonderful solution-- thanks ! Works for me on a Python 3.7.6 in Linux too.